# Getting syntax error when executing bulk import with mssql module on nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am using `mssql` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk) module to work with MSSQL database.

My code to make a bulk insert:

```
sql.connect("mssql://"+userName+":"+password+"@"+url).then(function() {
    var table = new sql.Table(tableName); // or temporary table, e.g. #temptable 
    table.rows.add("oto@test.com", "123");
    console.log("Table obj: "+JSON.stringify(table));
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.bulk(table, function(err, rowCount) {
        if (err){
            return callback("Error during executing a query: " + err);
        }
        return callback(null);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error during DB connection: "+err);
});
```

It says `Error during executing a query: Syntax error near ')'`

From the example presented in module documentation I have omitted table creation as my table already exists. Maybe that is causing it but when I include something like this:

```
table.create = false;
table.columns.add('EmailAddress', sql.VarChar(255), {nullable: false, primary: true});
table.columns.add('DataSourceId', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false});
```

It gives another error:

```
Error during executing a query: RequestError: Invalid column type from bcp clien
t for colid 2.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "*It says...*" where? why? when??

Comment: During Query execution. Stop being harass it's obvious. If I knew why I wouldn't be posting a question here

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question in case anyone else has the same issue.

First of all, the syntax error is not really going to point you into the right direction. I have figured out that it is a requirement to define table columns, even though you don't want to create a new table.

Then I was getting this error:

```
Error during executing a query: RequestError: Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 2.
```

That was because in JS code I said `DataSourceId` column cannot be null, but in fact the table I have created on `MSSQL` says it can be null. Meaning there was a mismatch and therefore the error.

Working code:

```
function insertToDb(tableName, contactData, callback){
    var userName = "foo";
    var password = "foo";
    var url = "foo";
    sql.connect("mssql://"+userName+":"+password+"@"+url).then(function() {
        var table = new sql.Table(tableName);
        table.create = false;
        table.columns.add('EmailAddress', sql.NVarChar(255), {nullable: false, primary: true});
        table.columns.add('DataSourceId', sql.NVarChar(50), {nullable: true});
        table.rows.add("oto@test.com", "123");

        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.bulk(table, function(err, rowCount) {
            if (err){
                return callback("Error during executing a query: " + err);
            }
            return callback(null);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error during DB connection: "+err);
    });
}
```